# Why we need gateway interface for web applications?

Tags: python, mod-wsgi

I am new to web applications and came across these two terms, WSGI and CGI. Well both are the gateway interfaces but my question is that why we need these interfaces for communication between server and web application? Can't they communicate directly?

Thanks

Comment: That *is* how they communicate.

Comment: "CGI interface" is not a program or any other "physical" object, it's a specification that both the server and the app have to follow to understand each other.

Comment: Yeah that is true! but I cant create image of this stuff in my mind somehow. I need to know Why we need a gateway interface?

Comment: "Interface" or "protocol" are just languages programs use to talk to each other. Just like we use English (ok, "international" English) to talk here. If everybody uses its own language, there is no communication.

Comment: So, what is WSGI server then?

Comment: Any example will be appreciated, like some code.

Answer (score 1):

When strings (data as bytestring) are received by a Web server it is needed some kind of 'adapter' to make possible for the application/Python environment to treat these strings. 
How the data is 'shipped' from the server/gateway environment into a application/Python environment is defined by WSGI. On the other way, from Python to server, when they are sent. See [PEP-3333](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/).
It's needed because software in the machine (applications) needs a way to communicate through the network using HTTP, Web server plus the CGI make it possible in a safe and standard way for Python-based applications.

Comment: So, can I say that apache is a server and I hosted my website which supports WSGI for communication using mod_wsgi. because perhaps without mod_wsgi apache would be unable to understand my app?

Comment: In PEP-3333, should I write server side code in .wsgi file and where should I put that file? in some apache directory? or should I put my application side file in apache directory for recieving requests?

Comment: @qurat how to make WSGI works depends from the Web server. In Apache there is a module called mod_wsgi for example: https://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/ Yeah, a Python-based server cannot work without mod_wsgi.